# IDX:20803 Unable to obtain configuration from... - Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

Hi I am trying to test a simple WebApi application with JWT token. Mainly, I have followed the example [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)

I am using https.

For the time-being, Authorization is not used. The issue is that everything works fine if I choose "Inherit auth from parent" in **Postman**.

As soon as I change option to "BearerToken" and try to enter the JSONWebToken that I received, it gives me

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44387/api/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
>    ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:44387/api/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
>    ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)

Please note, I am not using **IdentityServer** middleware here, and on browser also, I am unable to browse to https://localhost:44387/api/.well-known/openid-configuration

I am not sure where this **"openid-configuration"** is, specially when I am not explicitly using it in my **aspnet Core 3.0** web APi application? Here is my code..

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    { 
     //extra code removed for brevity
     //Authentication
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44387/api";
                options.Audience = "JWT:Issuer";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            });
 }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            //to send HTTP Strict Transport Security Protocol (HSTS) headers to clients.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseRouting();





        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapControllers();

            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Instead of *https://localhost:44387/api* I have also tried *https://localhost:44387/* and *https://localhost* but no luck.. I am mainly trying to understand why openid is coming up when I didnot use it at all. Everything is on my local machine and I am using IISExpress.

I have also tried deleting and recreating localhost SSL certificates by Repairing IISExpress.

Any clue will be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your setting of `AddJwtBearer` , it will contact the OIDC metadata document since you have set `Authority` , that is used to get service's public signing keys when validating jwt tokens which issued by private key of token service .

Your scenario is using the symmetric security key to issue/validate jwt tokens . So as the [document](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) shows , you should **Not** to set `Authority` , set `SymmetricSecurityKey` to validate token in the scenario :

```
var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

// configure jwt authentication
var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

Comment: Great! So two things I did not know, 1. Authority is basically providing public keys for signature..2. since my Startup code was already written I totally ignored that section from the example document :D...Thanks for pointing!!

Comment: This answer helped me make some useful changes to my authentication middleware for both front end and back end. First I was getting 401, then it started giving 500, on inspecting the frontend I realised that the token was always undefined when sending it to api which led to the 500 bad auth

Comment: see this commit for details:

https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-api/commit/6d6d30f82d8b8632150a5c3eca9acd61b5f387c4